# How can the vertical alignment of a range be changed without impacting the indent?

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel, when changing the vertical alignment of a range from the default of `xlBottom` to `xlCenter`, either with the normal user interface or with VBA like this:

```
Range.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
```

Excel sometimes removes the indent setting for text in those cells.  It appears to happen when the target range contains both indented and un-indented cells.

Using VBA, how can I set the vertical alignment for **any** range and preserve the cell indent for every cell in that range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `IndentLevel` property of a `Range`:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Dim indent As Long

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")

    For Each r In rng
        indent = r.IndentLevel
        r.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        r.IndentLevel = indent
    Next
End Sub
```

**Update**

As [Chris Neilson pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498282/how-can-the-vertical-alignment-of-a-range-be-changed-without-impacting-the-inden/49498377#comment86001909_49498377), when you loop through your cells changing the alignment individually it doesn't affect your indentation, whereas `rng.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter` does remove indentation on the whole range.

Therefore, here's the tested, quickest method so far (0.41s runtime on my laptop):

```
Sub Test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim t As Variant: t = Timer
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10000")

    For Each r In rng
        r.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Next

    Debug.Print Timer - t
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This would work only if (1) all cells in the range have the same indent level, and (2) I know the indent level beforehand.  I'm looking for a universal solution.

Comment: You're right.  I didn't read your caveat the first time through.

Comment: @ChrisB, updated (and removed caveat and now obsolete comments)

Comment: Gave this +1.  I turned off screen updating for the duration of the script and it reduced the time to format 10,000 cells from 8 seconds to 2 seconds.  Unless someone posts a more efficient (i.e. faster) method I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Chrisb because you are looping and setting alignment of one cell at a time you probably don't need to set indent too.  Removing that would speed it up a bit

Comment: Great spot @chrisneilsen.. I've updated for that gem!

Comment: Nice!  I timed it with a large sample.  The first  version of the answer completed in 13.7 seconds.  The current version with `ScreenUpdating` off and not indenting (nice one @Chris neilsen!) since it updates one cell at a time, completed in 3.05 seconds.  That's a 450% improvement!  I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: Another suggestion.  Changing the code in the loop to 'If r.VerticalAlignment <> xlCenter Then r.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter' runs significantly faster when there are many cells that are already vertically aligned to the center.